# Why box-shadow doesnt works in Safari, but in others browsers work?

Tags: sass, box-shadow

Last time i code some css to my website, after tests I forward that in Safari (11.1.2) box-shadow doesn't works . I tried to add prefix -webkit but it doesn't works too. Do you have some idea how I can fix it??

box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

Comment: Could you please explain what is the expected behavior and what you actually observe

Comment: I tried to add shadow to table rows similar like here: tiny.cc/b1zj9y and I forward that in Chrome, Firefox, IE etc works, but in Safari doesn't. I have to mention that in other cases box shadow works ( eg in buttons)

Comment: Problem solved, I change 'box-shadow' to 'filter: drop-shadow()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/soniaj204/pen/LKaYRp), it works in safari browser

```
<div></div>
div {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
```

May be you can try giving a value 0.9 rather than 0.12 and just check if it works for you or not. As 0.12 might be working but it is just not visible to eyes may be